# Pymongo Client find not working properly

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

When requesting data from Pythons MongoClient (with connection to the same database and requesting from the same collection) i get less in my result (with or without filtering)

`for example requesting db.collection.find({})`

in the shell gives me 12 results and the same query in pymongo gives me 8, with 4 missing, using filtering i get one result instead of 4 (for those missing)

Are anyone else having troubles with pythons mongoclient?

when running (in shell)

```
db.test.find() i get the result
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b4138044"), "account" : "1234", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b473177310ea1023a4f434f"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:58.780Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b4138045"), "account" : "12345", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b3f36df42db3e021a3b2689"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:58.929Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b4138046"), "account" : "32124", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b43bf9a51dac70058ffa43c"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:58.856Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b4138047"), "account" : "44112", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b4a464c94e89c00cb61d001"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-26T04:00:58.803Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b4138049"), "account" : "44115", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b56d464d862440046ccf1fa"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:58.764Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b413804a"), "account" : "414141", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b473ea7310ea10827c4886b"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:58.986Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58623a89ca2c00755e12d7"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b695283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:50.009Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12da"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T17:42:57.022Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12db"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "cat" : "70058", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T11:43:57.483Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12dc"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "cat" : "70058", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T11:43:57.488Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12dd"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "cat" : "70058", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T11:43:57.493Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12de"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "cat" : "70058", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T11:43:57.497Z") }

when db.test.find({"account":"444444", "tag": "nice"}) i get

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58623a89ca2c00755e12d7"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b695283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:50.009Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12da"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T17:42:57.022Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12db"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "cat" : "70058", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T11:43:57.483Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12dc"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "cat" : "70058", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T11:43:57.488Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12dd"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "cat" : "70058", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T11:43:57.493Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12de"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "cat" : "70058", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T11:43:57.497Z") }
```

For the same queries through PyMongo i get

```
(no filter) 

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b4138044"), "account" : "1234", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b473177310ea1023a4f434f"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:58.780Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b4138045"), "account" : "12345", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b3f36df42db3e021a3b2689"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:58.929Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b4138046"), "account" : "32124", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b43bf9a51dac70058ffa43c"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:58.856Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b4138047"), "account" : "44112", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b4a464c94e89c00cb61d001"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-26T04:00:58.803Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b4138049"), "account" : "44115", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b56d464d862440046ccf1fa"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:58.764Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b581e4bd8624400b413804a"), "account" : "414141", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b473ea7310ea10827c4886b"), "start" : false, "tag" : "hello", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:58.986Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58623a89ca2c00755e12d7"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b695283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T22:00:50.009Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12da"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T17:42:57.022Z") }

(acccount and tag filter)

    { "_id" : ObjectId("5b58624189ca2c00755e12da"), "account" : "444444", "job_id" : ObjectId("5b58623989ca2c00b995283f"), "area" : "238428477", "start" : false, "tag" : "nice", "time" : ISODate("2018-07-25T17:42:57.022Z") }
```

How i connect through pymongo

```
host = config['host']
port = config['port']
db_name = config['db_name']

db = MongoClient(host, port)[db_name]

and then i just run with and without filters, still different result
db.collection.find()
```

Comment: Can you pls post the code which you have written to try this? Without that, we cannot figure out what could have gone wrong.

Comment: I updated the question with dummy examples

Comment: I need the exact statement which you use to query using Pymongo. Can you post that?

Comment: Added how i connect